# Collaborating using forks and pull requests

Tags: git, github

I'm about to join a SW team and I just have a few questions regarding collaboration using git. I understand that some of these answers may vary depending on the team I join and their preferences but I'd definitely appreciate some insight as to how *you* and your team collaborate.

My understanding is that the existing code will be hosted on GitHub and I will fork and then clone to my machine. Each time there is new code in the upstream, I would sync my fork.

1) If a team member makes a pull request and it gets merged onto the upstream, I would fetch/merge that new code. Do I update my fork by fetching & merging from the upstream, committing, and then pushing onto my forked repo?

2) Is it common for team members to fork each other's forks or only from the upstream? My guess is that you would fork a team member's fork if they needed help but, then again, that team member could make a pull request for a new branch to the upstream and then I would just fetch that branch from the upstream. Or is the upstream only for features that are fully complete and ready to be implemented into production?

3) Now that I have completed a task, I would commit to my local master branch, then push to my fork, then I would make a pull request from my fork to the upstream. Is this the correct workflow? Is there a better/more common way? Do I make a pull request from one of the branches on my fork or directly from my local branch to the upstream?

Answer (score 1):

A [fork](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo) is only needed if you have no write access to the repository, or don't want to touch the original repository for some reason. Otherwise, you just need a branch in the repo.

If you work as part of a team, you usually have access to the repository and there is no need to complicate the workflow with a fork - you can clone the original repo directly and do all changes in your local cloned copy. Then push them to your personal branch in the repo, and create a pull request from it to e.g. master branch.

If you want to help a colleague - just check out his branch. Again, there is no need in any forks, and especially in forking someone's fork.

Comment: I see. That makes perfect sense. How are "issues" used in a team environment? Does the team lead create an issue and assign it to a person (in conjunction with using some scrum tool such as trello or jira)? I've seen in some tutorials that an issue will be created (lets say issue #3) and in my pull request I would put "Closes Issue #3".

Comment: I believe this fully depends on the team and the tools in use.